# pass image path in second activity and display it

Tags: android, image, android-activity, path

Here is the code. 
I tried to pass the image path from my Main_Activity to this new Activity, but the image is not being displayed in New_Activity.

So my question is: How is it possible to display the image in New_Activity by passing the path from the Main_Activity?

Is there any easier method to do such a thing?

Please explain it with details if possible.
Example codes are welcome too... 
Thanks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String filename = extras.getString("map1");
            FileInputStream is = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
                } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                //Try to recover
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }  

            myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

here is the logcat file:

```
07-30 20:36:46.601: W/MapDbAdapter(387): 5
07-30 20:37:33.161: D/AndroidRuntime(387): Shutting down VM
07-30 20:37:33.161: W/dalvikvm(387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.activity.map/com.example.activity.map.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at com.example.activity.map.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:48)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-30 20:37:33.172: E/AndroidRuntime(387):  ... 11 more
```

THis is the new logcat file:

07-30 21:12:25.921: W/MapDbAdapter(493): 5
07-30 21:12:28.621: D/AndroidRuntime(493): Shutting down VM
07-30 21:12:28.621: W/dalvikvm(493): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.activity.map/com.example.activity.map.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at com.example.activity.map.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:29)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-30 21:12:28.631: E/AndroidRuntime(493):  ... 11 more

The error was in line number 29: i got it : here is also my java code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("map1");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);

    if (bitmap != null) {
        myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
        } 



            myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
//      private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName){
//            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
//            InputStream istr = null;
//            try {
//                istr = assetManager.open(strName);
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
//            return bitmap;
//        }
}
```

Comment: are you getting a error?

Comment: ya it says null pointer exception! but i dont know what is the problem !do you have any idea how does it really works or any other tutorial to get to know more about passing image path and getting to display the image in newactivity ! thanks in advance

Comment: Is your image in Drawable folder?

Comment: please paste the stacktrace, that's the first thing you should post when you have an error

Comment: No my image is in assets folder: for that i have to pass the path of the image in the assets folder.

Comment: This will answer your question: [Load an image from assets folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734803/load-an-image-from-assets-folder)

Comment: hey Dheeraj, there is no stacktrace for the first Main_Activity part ! the application runs in the emulator but when i click and go to the New_Activity application crashes and i get the above log cat message as error !

Comment: Which line 48 in Activity2? Plus you can't access assets folder like that. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("map1");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);

    if (bitmap != null) {
        myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
        }
```

Comment: hey i used your code, everything works but the image is not getting displayed ! why !!!

Answer (score 0):

## This is how you show image from Assets folder

What you're doing is incorrect. Use this code and let usknow.

You can use `AssetManager` to get the InputStream using its `open()` method and then use `decodeStream()` method of `BitmapFactory` to get the Bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: 07-30 20:46:08.961: W/MapDbAdapter(411): 5
07-30 20:46:39.331: D/AndroidRuntime(411): Shutting down VM
07-30 20:46:39.331: W/dalvikvm(411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-30 20:46:39.341: E/AndroidRuntime(411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 20:46:39.341: E/AndroidRuntime(411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.activity.map/com.example.activity.map.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 20:46:39.341: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: On which line is the NPE? Please update your question with these stacktraces as formatting is lost in comments and it's difficult to read. Just leave me a comment when you update your question with what I've asked.

Comment: hey Dheeraj ! i have updated the code ! the error was in line 29 ! now i got it !

Comment: @Niranjan what was the mistake in your code, what did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Set the path for Image and Save your image to SD card after that Send your image path(image path you get as a string) to next Activity and get Image Again with image path.

Save Image to Sd Card and create an image Path for your Bitmap

```
private void saveImage() {
    File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/YOUR_DIR/");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("log_check", "failed to create directory");
            return;
        }
    }
    String fileName= "your_file_name"

    savedFileName = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath(), fileName
            + ".jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savedFileName);

        yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException", e + "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", e + "");
    }

}
```

**Send your "fileName" to next Activity.**

On Next Activty You can create again a BitMap with your file name like below code.

```
String imagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imagePath");
Bitmap yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of the question. and it works perfectly !But i am passing image instead of passing the path of image and it is much easier !

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

            ImageView gallerypic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
/*Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key or a null value is explicitly associated with the key.
*/
            String backgroundpath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("maps");


            if(getImageFromAssert(backgroundpath)!=null){
/*Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.*/
                gallerypic.setImageDrawable(getImageFromAssert(backgroundpath));
            }
        }

        private Drawable getImageFromAssert(String name){
            try {
/*read the image file from the assets */
                InputStream ims = getAssets().open(name);
/*create a drawable from the inputstream and return it */
                return Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```