# showing .mov file from assets to Imageview Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, assets, .mov

I have a .mov file for a custom progress in my application and i have to display it using a ImageView.

I have tried all the solutions mentioned in below link but nothing seems to be working:

[Load an image from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734803/load-an-image-from-assets-folder)

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("file:///android_asset/setting_up_profile.mov",
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProgress);
       iv.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

And

```
 InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(path);
 Drawable d= Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);--> d is returned as null
```

Can anybody help me how can i show this .mov file or should i move it from assets to raw or drawables.

Comment: `.mov` is file extension usually associated with [a video file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format). You cannot display a video in an `ImageView`. Also, that file format (QuickTime) is not supported by Android even as a video format, last I checked.

Comment: @Thanks, But can i extract Thumbnails from .mov and display it as mentioned http://error.news/question/2213454/how-to-get-the-thumbnail-from-mov-files-in-android  and http://error.news/question/2213454/how-to-get-the-thumbnail-from-mov-files-in-android/   But keeping it in assets