# Is inline created InputStream closed automatically by GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inputstream

I've found several similar questions, but I still can't find the answer to my question.

I know that it is enough to close the outer stream and it will close inner stream which is created in line.

```
BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
br.close();
```

Consider next example

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(configPath));
```

Should the `FileInputStream` be assigned to a variable and then closed explicitly (or with try-with-resource construction) or will Java GC close it automatically right after `props.load()` method invocation, because there is no reference to the resource?

Comment: What do you mean by `GB`?

Comment: You should not rely on garbage collector to do resource release. Correct answer to your question is "_it might, or might not_".

Comment: To elaborate on @M.Prokhorov 's comment: there is no guarantee when the garbage collector will do its work, in principle it can delay its job indefinitely, which means the resource will remain allocated indefinitely, which is not what you want. Close resources explicitly instead of relying on GC.

Comment: @biziclop Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javadoc states that

> The specified stream remains open after this method returns.

So yes, you should close it yourself if you want to write clean code. The GC will close it eventually, **if** it gets around to calling the `finalize()` method (shown below) on the stream, but you [shouldn't rely on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java).

Always close your resources, that's the only way to be sure.

```
/**
 * Ensures that the <code>close</code> method of this file input stream is
 * called when there are no more references to it.
 *
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FileInputStream#close()
 */
protected void finalize() throws IOException {
    if ((fd != null) &&  (fd != FileDescriptor.in)) {
        /* if fd is shared, the references in FileDescriptor
         * will ensure that finalizer is only called when
         * safe to do so. All references using the fd have
         * become unreachable. We can call close()
         */
        close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It must be emphasized that using code like

```
BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
// you likely insert actual operations on br here
br.close();
```

is strongly discouraged, as the closing will not happen, if an operation between the stream construction and the `close()` call throws an exception.

You should use the “try with resource” construct instead:

```
try(BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    // your actual operations on br here
}
```

This ensures that `close()` will be called even if an exception occurs in the `try` body. However, this code relies on the known fact that the `BufferedInputStream`’s `close()` method will call the `FileInputStream`’s `close()` method, but this does not happen until the construction of the `BufferedInputStream` has been completed. If the `BufferedInputStream`’s constructor throws an exception, it’s `close()` method will not be called, as there is no object to call `close()` on.

A really safe solution is

```
try(FileInputStream    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
    // your actual operations on br here
}
```

which closes the `FileInputStream` even if the constructor of `BufferedInputStream` throws an exception. That might look like a rare corner case here, as the only thing which can go wrong in that constructor would be the buffer allocation which could throw an `OutOfMemoryError` and you are in deep trouble anyway in that case.

But consider an example like

```
try(FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    // your actual operations on ois here
}
```

Since the constructor of `ObjectInputStream` already reads the header, `IOException`s may be thrown, also, the header might be invalid, which would also cause an exception. Hence, there’s a lot more which can go wrong and ensuring that the underlying `FileInputStream` is properly closed even in these cases is much more important.