# I am trying to loading image fom Drawable and it is not showing any image in imageview

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-drawable, webp

I have 700 images in Drawable  and i have a list of image name and i need to load it into imageview programily
Image is in webp formate and less than 100kb 
   images in recycler view

where is wrong

Java Code

```
Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mData.get(position).getImage(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()));             
    holder.image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Layout

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fish_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

I have 700 images in Drawable and I have a list of image name and I need to load it into image view programmatically is there any other solution

Update it worked 
 i moved image to    Assets folder and load it from there

```
try {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = mContext.getAssets().open(mData.get(position).getImagename()+".webp");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(d);
            ims .close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e("image_io",ex.getMessage()+"");
           // return;
        }
```

Comment: Please share imageview height and width

Comment: i have 700 images in Drawable  and i have a list of image name and i need to load it into imageview programily

Comment: How to use setImageResource() ?

Comment: What is `getIdentifier()` returning there? What is `getImage()` returning? Do you actually have a drawable resource by that name, applicable to the current configuration? What happens if you temporarily use the `R.drawable` value? For that matter, why aren't you just using the `R.drawable` values in your data model to begin with?

Comment: getImage() return string example "Malawi_shell_dweller"

Answer (score 1):

You should use the name of the drawable as string and not `getImageuri()`:

```
Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()));
```

Comment: image uri is string

Comment: Why do you need a uri for images in drawable folder?

Comment: Is getImageuri().toString() just the name of the drawable, or not? Check it.

Comment: I have 700 images in Drawable and I have a list of image name and I need to load it into image view programmatically is there any other solution?

Comment: getImageuri() return image  name like   "Malawi_shell_dweller"

Comment: In this code where i need to add image name ?<br>    Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()));
 <br>

Comment: replace drawable_name with the name of the drawble

Comment: @Midhilaj 700 images? so add them to "assets" folder and use `android.content.res.AssetManager` for getting them in your app

Comment: @Midhilaj did you read `AssetManager` docs? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: now i am trying with this code<br>
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734850/4650969

Comment: but not woking .

Comment: @Midhilaj Try with just one single drawable's name. If this does not work then the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @Midhilaj what is `"not working"`? is `InputStream ims` null or what?

Comment: @Midhilaj and of course cache those `Drawable`s in some `HashMap<String, Drawable>` so that you call `Drawable.createFromStream` only once for given name

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri_for_drawable = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.your_image_name)
                + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.your_image_name) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.your_image_name) );
```

Use the above code to get the image uri from drawable folder.