# Where to find assets in the Device File Explorer of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, assets

I've created an asset folder and placed my GUI.png image in it (left image).
But i can't find the image in the Device File Explorer after the app is started in the AVD emulator.

Where was it placed?
Is it supposed to be in /data/data (right image) ?

[image]

Comment: Assets are packed inside the APK. Use  `Context.getAssets().open(fileName)` to get a stream for reading. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734899/2444099)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll get it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android allow us to use two parts of memeory:
1 as internal
and
1 as external (generally refered as SD card).

"Device File Explorer" is used to see the internal files (that too in debug mode).
Your "data" folder is part of source (code), it has nothing to be seen in internal storage folder of app in device.
You will see a file inside "data/data/" folder, if specifically you have written code to copy it there.